# Bifurcation diagram for SIR model

Tags: r

This R code is for the bifurcation diagram for the nonautonomous Two-Patch SIR model.

Please help me to run this code. The code is correct until making the data set. I am not understanding the range limit and how should I plot it? Any help will be appreciable.

```
############### SIR Model ################
library(deSolve)
sir.two.patch.model <- function (t, x, params){
  #create local variable IA, IB, RA, RB, SA, SB
  IA <- x[1]
  IB <- x[2]
  RA <- x[3]
  RB <- x[4]
  SA <- x[5]
  SB <- x[6]
  #we can simplify code using "with"
  #this argument to "with" lets us use the variable Names
  with(
    as.list(params),
    {               
      dIA <- betaAbar*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IA*SA/Na-(muA+gamaA+phiIAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*IA+phiIBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IB
      dIB <- betaBbar*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IB*SB/NB-(muB+gamaB+phiIBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*IB +phiIAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IA
      dRA <- gamaA*IA-(muA+phiRAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*RA+phiRBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*RB
      dRB <- gamaB*IB-(muB+phiRBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*RB+phiRAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*RA
      dSA <- muA*Na-betaAbar*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IA*SA/Na-(muA+phiSAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*SA+phiSBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*SB
      dSB <- muB*NB-betaBbar*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*IB*SB/NB-(muB+phiSBA*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti)))*SB+phiSAB*(1+sigA*cos(2*pi*t/Ti))*SA
      #combine results into a single vector dx
      dx <- c(dIA,dIB,dRA,dRB,dSA,dSB)
      #return result as a list
      return(list(dx))
    }
  )
}

n <- 100 # number of simulations
param.name <- "betaAbar" # choose parameter to perturb
param.seq <- seq(0,80,length = 5) # choose range of parameters

params <- c(Na=100, NB=1000, betaAbar=60, betaBbar=5,muA=0.06, muB=0.02, gamaA=12, gamaB=12,phiIAB=0.4, phiIBA=0.04, phiSAB=0.4, phiSBA=0.04, phiRAB=0.4, phiRBA=0.04, sigA=0.5,Ti=1)
times <- seq(0,100,length.out=3000)
xstart <- c(IA=5,IB=5,RA=0,RB=0,SA=100-5,SB=1000-5)

param.index <- which(param.name == names(params))
out <- list()
for (i in 1:length(param.seq))
  out[[i]] <- matrix(0, n, length(xstart))

for (i in 1:length(param.seq)) {
  # set params
  params.loop <- params
  params.loop[param.index] <- param.seq[i]
  # converge
  init <- ode(xstart, times, sir.two.patch.model, params.loop)
  # get converged points
  out[[i]] <- ode(init[n,-1], times, sir.two.patch.model, params.loop)[,-1]
}

range.lim <- lapply(out, function(IA) apply(IA, 2, range))
range.lim <- apply(do.call("rbind", range.lim), 2, range)
plot.variable <- "IA" # choose which variable to show
plot(0, 0, pch = "", xlab = param.name, ylab = plot.variable,
     xlim = range(param.seq), ylim = range.lim[,plot.variable])
#plot(0, 0, pch = "", xlab = "betaAbar", ylab = "IA")
for (i in 1:length(param.seq)) {
  points(rep(param.seq[i], n), out[[i]][,plot.variable])
}
```

Comment: Not sure which kind of plot do you want, however the `plot` command fails because `rep(param.seq[i],n)` has length `n` (100), whereas `out[[i]][,plot.variable]` has length `length(times)` (3000).

Comment: I am looking for a bifurcation plot betaAbar verses IA. I changed the length of n to 3000 instead of 100. But still, it's not working.